# Redux-Persist don't save store to localStorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, persist

Redux-Persist don't save store to localStorage, does anyone have any ideas?

store.js

```js
import { createInjectorsEnhancer } from 'redux-injectors';
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { createReducer } from './createReducer';

export function configureStore() {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware];

  const persistConfig = {
    key: 'root',
    storage,
  };

  const enhancers = [
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run,
    }),
  ];

  const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, createReducer());
  const store = createStore(persistedReducer, {}, composeWithDevTools(...enhancers));
  const persistor = persistStore(store);

  return { store, persistor };
}
```

createReducer.js

```js
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

export function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  return combineReducers({
    ...injectedReducers,
  });
}
```

Components:

```js
import { bindActionCreators, Dispatch } from 'redux';
import { ActionType } from 'typesafe-actions';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useInjectReducer, useInjectSaga } from 'redux-injectors';
import * as Actions from './actions';
import { ComponentReducer } from './reducer';
import { ComponentSaga } from './saga';

function Component({ }: ComponentProps) {
  useInjectReducer({ key: 'Component', reducer: ComponentReducer });
  useInjectSaga({ key: 'Component', saga: ComponentSaga });

  return <></>;
}

type ComponentProps- = {
   // types
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch<ActionType<typeof Actions>>) =>
  bindActionCreators(
    {
      // methods,
    },
    dispatch,
  );

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  // selectors
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

app.js

```jsx
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router } from 'react-router';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import App from './containers/App';
import { configureStore } from '../utils/configureStore';
import { history } from '../appHistory';

const { store, persistor } = configureStore();

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <App />
        </Router>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root'),
);
```

It looks like a normal application structure, but it doesn't work.
I think 90% the problem is in dynamic inject reducers with redux-injectors. I tried to use the old way inject like, but still useless.

```js
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist-immutable';
import createFilter from 'redux-persist-transform-filter-immutable';
import createReducer from './reducers';

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  // Create the store with two middlewares
  // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
  // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];

  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

  enhancers.push(autoRehydrate());
  // If Redux DevTools Extension is installed use it, otherwise use Redux compose
  /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle, indent */
  const composeEnhancers =
    process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
      ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({ trace: true })
      : compose;
  /* eslint-enable */

  const store = createStore(createReducer(), fromJS(initialState), composeEnhancers(...enhancers));

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'test') {
    const stateFilter = createFilter('global', [
      'abonent',
      'version',
      'products',
      'showWorkSpaces',
      'error',
      'settings',
    ]);

    window.persistor = persistStore(store, {
      whitelist: ['global', 'sprinterSidebar'],
      transforms: [stateFilter],
    });
  }
  // Extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

  return store;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good problem statement. Please read [ask] for hints on how to construct a question that will be less likely to be downvoted and closed. Also, don't use Stack Snippets unless a) you're going to put actual HTML in the HTML box (not JavaScript), if needed, and b) they do something when you click "Run code snippet".

Comment: Use react-native-async-storage: https://github.com/react-native-async-storage/async-storage

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in a similar situation just last week, and just like you, I also inject reducers at runtime, which is what I eventually discovered was causing this issue.

The solution is simply to call the `persistor.persit()` method after injecting a new reducer. You will probably have to look up how to do this for [`redux-injectors`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-injectors) library that you are using. In my case, I use a simple function to do this:

```
/**
 * dynamically injects a reducer at runtime
 * @param key an identifier for this reducer
 * @param reducer The reducer
 * @param blacklist do not persist the reducer state
 */
const injectReducer = <RState>(key: string, reducer: Reducer<RState, AnyAction>, blacklist = false) => {
    if (!(key in asyncReducers)) {
        asyncReducers[key] = reducer;
        if (blacklist) {
            asyncBlacklist.push(key);
        }
        appStore.replaceReducer(createReducer(asyncReducers, asyncBlacklist));
        storeEvents.emit("root-reducer-change"); // or persistor.persist()
    }
};
```

*`storeEvents` is an [`EventEmitter3`](https://github.com/primus/eventemitter3) object.*

...and this is where I register the listener to then persist the store:

```
export const store = { ...appStore, injectReducer };
export const persistor = persistStore(appStore);

storeEvents.on("root-reducer-change", () => persistor.persist());
```

---

Another strange (and might be the most frustrating) part to understanding what was going on, is that having the [redux devtools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) installed seems to hide this problem. So my advice to any developer working with redux is to:

> make sure you **DISABLE REDUX DEVTOOLS EXTENSION atleast once** during your testing,
> otherwise users of your app may be experiencing something different from what you assumed was true about your application.

Sources:

- https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/issues/1287
- https://github.com/rematch/rematch/issues/890